# Accessing multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've made a multidimensional array by doing an array.push on the inner and outer arrays. and I'm trying to get the array[0]'s length. I know I can't do that because .length in javascript only works if the array values are numerical. array[0] also returns undefined so am I not working with arrays as I think I am but some sort of objects instead? Sorry if the question is vague. I just don't know what I'm looking at.

[what the array looks like in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDOTG.png)

```
getMapInfo = filterArray => {
    var paramArray = [];
    var locationArr = [];
    var namesArr = [];
    var ratingsArr = [];
    var addressesArr = [];
    var placeIDArr = [];
    axios
      .get(
        `${"https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"}https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
          },
          params: {
            categories: "coffee, libraries",
            latitude: this.state.currentLocation.lat,
            longitude: this.state.currentLocation.lng,
            limit: 20
          }
        }
      )
      // set state for locations, names
      .then(res => {
        for (var key in res.data.businesses) {
          var addressesBase = res.data.businesses[key].location;

          locationArr.push(res.data.businesses[key].coordinates);
          placeIDArr.push(res.data.businesses[key].id);
          namesArr.push(res.data.businesses[key].name);
          ratingsArr.push(res.data.businesses[key].rating);
          addressesArr.push(
            "" +
              addressesBase.address1 +
              " " +
              addressesBase.city +
              ", " +
              addressesBase.state +
              " " +
              addressesBase.zip_code
          );
        }
        if (filterArray === undefined) {
          this.setState({
            placeID: placeIDArr,
            locations: locationArr,
            names: namesArr,
            ratings: ratingsArr,
            addresses: addressesArr
          });
        }

        paramArray.push(placeIDArr);
        paramArray.push(locationArr);
        paramArray.push(namesArr);
        paramArray.push(ratingsArr);
        paramArray.push(addressesArr);
      })

      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Yelp API call error");
      });
    if (filterArray !== undefined) {
      //console.log of paramArray[0] returns undefined 
     // console.log of paramArray is what is seen in the image 

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(paramArray);
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: "I know I can't do that because .length in javascript only works if the array values are numerical." This isn't true. If it's an array the `.length` property will return the length of the array no matter what data type the items are. Run this and you'll see what I mean: `["string", 2, 5, [1,2,3], {hello: "you"}].length`, it returns `5`

Comment: Also you're going to need to see this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask otherwise people will likely downvote your questions

Comment: try log `console.log(paramArray.length && paramArray[0])`

Answer (score 0):

You are working with arrays correctly. The reason `paramArray[0]` returns `undefined` is because you are pushing to the array inside your `.then` function, which happens *after* the Axios call finishes - your `console.log` statements are outside of the `.then` function, causing them to run **immediately** instead of waiting for the Axios call (and therefore the array.push).

The simple solution is to move this part of your code inside the `.then()` callback:

```js
if (filterArray !== undefined) {
  //console.log of paramArray[0] returns undefined 
  // console.log of paramArray is what is seen in the image 

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(paramArray);
  });
}
```

Why is this necessary? Here's a simpler example to demonstrate:

```js
let x = 0

// wait 1 second, then set x to 1
setTimeout(() => {
  x = 1
}, 1000)

console.log(x)
```

What will be logged in the above example? You might initally think `1` would be logged, but actually it will log `0`. This is because the code inside the callback is `asynchronous` (just like your Axios call), meaning it will wait in the background to run at a later time. Meanwhile, your code will continue executing, resulting in the `console.log` to be different than you expect.

What if we want to wait until x is set to 1? Then we would move our log into the callback.

```js
let x = 0

// wait 1 second, then set x to 1
setTimeout(() => {
  x = 1
  console.log(x)
}, 1000)
```

Now, x will log `1`. This is a simpler version of the exact problem you faced with Axios.

To read deeper on this topic, look for information on the JavaScript Call Stack. Here's a great article on it: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/understanding-the-javascript-call-stack-861e41ae61d4/

Comment: in your 2nd example, i understand why it would wait to log the 1, but doesn't asynchronous mean that another function or whatever will run even if another function is running? As in, it doesn't need to wait for something else to finish to run?

Comment: @mph85 Yes, exactly. An asynchronous function will not block the main thread. So, when you run `axios.get` with a callback to `.then`, the callback will not run until the Axios call is finished - but that entire process is asynchronous because the rest of your code continues to run. That's why your logs are running before the `push`es are running.

Comment: ah icic, so the `get` request needs to finish first before the `then` promise can be run but otherwise any other processes will not be hindered and will continue to run even if any other function or whatnot is running